# Push redmine to the root of a subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, redmine, passenger

I just installed redmine and I would like to reach it from redmine.domain.com instead of domain.com/redmine.

I first tried to do this by myself with my few Apache knowledge but I got the following error:
[image: Cannot start Ruby On Rails application]

So I looked for a support on the internet and found [this page](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_deploying_to_a_virtual_host_8217_s_root_2). I consequently adapted my Apache configuration file:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName  redmine.mydomain.com
    ServerAdmin admin@mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/redmine

    <Directory /var/www/redmine>
        Allow from all
        Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ssl_access.log combined

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/private/redmine.mydomain.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/redmine.mydomain.com.key
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

And made some check ups, all seems good. However, when I go to my redmine.mydomain.com I see the hierarchy of /usr/share/redmine/public.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To cite from the page you linked to:

> The virtual host’s document root must point to your Rack application’s public folder.

Thus, you have to configure Apache's `DocumentRoot` to point to `/var/www/redmine/public`.

Comment: Actually /var/www/redmine is a symlink that points to /usr/share/redmine/public

Comment: That won't work. Passenger needs the document root to point to the public directory **and** needs to find the actual rails/rack app when going one directory up.

Comment: Hmmm OK I understand. When the DocumentRoot pointed to /var/www and I browsed domain.com/redmine, it actually went to /usr/share/redmine/public since the FollowSymLink option was set. But when I made the DocumentRoot pointing to /var/www/redmine, it didn't know that /var/www/redmine was a symlink, and thought the parent directory was /var/www. Am I right ?